# How to retrieve user Custom Field on row selected event Acumatica

Tags: c#, acumatica

My use case is that when making a bill, the client wants to be able to specify a portion of the bill amount to which no discount is applied. (eg the total bill is $125, and the customer gets a 10% discount for paying in cash on delivery, but the discount does not apply to shipping costs. So, they want to say: "$25 of this is not discountable")

Then, I want to override the discount amount field based on this custom field.

I have added a data field to my APInvoice DAC via the Customization editor, and then activated it in my C# code as an extension:

```
namespace AcmeCorp.DAC
{
    [PXCacheName("APInvoice")]
    public class APInvoiceExt : PXCacheExtension<APInvoice>
    {
        public static bool IsActive()  { return true; }
        // Auto-Generated from ERP Customization Editor
        #region UsrAmountExcludedFromDiscount
        [PXDBDouble()]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Amt Excluded Discount")]
        public virtual double? UsrAmountExcludedFromDiscount { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrAmountExcludedFromDiscount : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDouble.Field<usrAmountExcludedFromDiscount> { }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Now I want to check the value in that field to know how to adjust the discount field. How do I get this value?

[EDIT]
This allows me to get the extension, but the value is null, even though I have checked the record, and there is a value present there.

I set up a using statement first:

```
using APInvoiceExtension = Acme.DAC.APInvoiceExt;
```

And then I can use that in the GetExtension() method:

```
    protected virtual void _(Events.RowSelected<APInvoice> e)
    {
        if (e.Row == null) return;
        double? Amt2Exclude = null;

        APInvoice apInvoice = e.Row as APInvoice;

        var chkRef = apInvoice.RefNbr;
        var ext = PXCache<APInvoice>.GetExtension<APInvoiceExtension>(apInvoice);
        if (ext != null)
        {
            Amt2Exclude = ext.UsrAmountExcludedFromDiscount;
        }
    }
```

The RefNbr has a value just fine. But, as I said the value for UsrAmountExcludedFromDiscount is null.

[EDIT]
I tried Rick's suggestion and got the same error:
[image]

Comment: PXCache<APInvoice>.GetExtension<APInvoiceExt >(apInvoice);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things I'm kind of confused about, like your DAC has the namespace AcmeCorp.DAC in the code example but you have a using statement that uses a different namespace. I would also probably use a decimal over a double for your data type in this instance, and in any instance where you are working with currencies.

For retrieving an extension, you can simply do the following.

```
protected virtual void _(Events.RowSelected<APInvoice> eventHandler)
{
    APInvoice row = eventHandler.Row;
    if (row is null) return;

    APInvoiceExtension rowExt = row.GetExtension<APInvoiceExtension>();

    if (rowExt != null)
    {
        excludedAmount = rowExt.UsrAmountExcludedFromDiscount;
    }
}
```

I would probably avoid renaming the extension from APInvoiceExt to APInvoiceExtension on your using statement, but the above code should work to retrieve the extension. If you still have a null value in your extension, I would say that's most likely because a value never gets assigned to it, and you may need to post more of the code for us to evaluate what's actually going on here.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the solution, because it is the cleanest example. The reality is that I had some weird thing happen where it changed the name of the Custom field in the Custom Data Script. IDK how or when it happened. But after I set the value in my test record. So, it wasn't in the SQL database, but it was still showing on the screen. After I fixed that, everything worked fine. (Oh, and I also changed it from Double to decimal...)

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
APInvoiceExt  ext = PXCache<APInvoice>.GetExtension<APInvoiceExt>(apInvoice);
```

EDIT:

```
namespace PX.Objects.AP
{

  public class APRegisterExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.AP.APRegister>
  {
    #region UsrAmountExcludedFromDiscount
    [PXDBDecimal]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="Amt Excluded Discount")]
    public virtual Decimal? UsrAmountExcludedFromDiscount { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrAmountExcludedFromDiscount : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDecimal.Field<usrAmountExcludedFromDiscount> { }
    #endregion
  }
  
  
  public class APInvoiceEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<APInvoiceEntry>
  {
    #region Event Handlers

    protected void APInvoice_RowSelecting(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.Row == null) return;
      decimal? Amt2Exclude = null;
      APRegister apInvoice = e.Row as APRegister;

      var chkRef = apInvoice.RefNbr;
      var ext = PXCache<APRegister>.GetExtension<APRegisterExt>(apInvoice);
      if (ext != null)
      {
          Amt2Exclude = ext.UsrAmountExcludedFromDiscount;
      }  
      PXTrace.WriteInformation($"REF : {apInvoice.RefNbr}");
    }

    #endregion
  }
}
```

Comment: Sadly, no. Same error. (I took a screenshot of it, I'll add it to my original post.)

Comment: made changes above. custom field is added on APRegister actually. So probably need to subclass APInvoice to APRegister in the RowSelecting event.

Comment: Nice catch on the APRegister. Even tho I didn't add the field there, somehow, one showed up there, and this was part of the problem. I wish I knew what caused the problem, but once I fixed it in the ERP Customization editors, everything else worked fine. Thx for the help.